# Generating approximate polygon for circle with given radius and centre (without using shapely)

Tags: python, wgs84, circle

I am given center and radius (in km), I want to generate coordinates for the circle.

Every example on GIS.SE uses Shapely.

Is there any way to do it in python without using Shapely?

Comment: x = r cos theta, y = r sin theta. Iterate over theta between 0 and 2 pi. The more angles,  the better the approximation.

Comment: @wingnut that's for a circle centred at 0,0 of course!

Comment: @Spacedman And for a projected spatial reference, of course!

Comment: what do you mean by "generate coordinates"? Are you expecting lat/long coordinates? If that's what you mean, then not even shapely can do that.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of what @wingnut and @Spacedman said, here's a quick and simple reproducible example that only uses the `math` library:

```py
import math

# This function gets just one pair of coordinates based on the angle theta
def get_circle_coord(theta, x_center, y_center, radius):
    x = radius * math.cos(theta) + x_center
    y = radius * math.sin(theta) + y_center
    return (x,y)

# This function gets all the pairs of coordinates
def get_all_circle_coords(x_center, y_center, radius, n_points):
    thetas = [i/n_points * math.tau for i in range(n_points)]
    circle_coords = [get_circle_coord(theta, x_center, y_center, radius) for theta in thetas]
    return circle_coords

# Using the second function to generate all the pairs of coordinates.
circle_coords = get_all_circle_coords(x_center = 5, 
                                      y_center = 15,
                                      radius = 2.5,
                                      n_points = 5000)
```

The `circle_coords` variable is a list that holds all of the pairs of coordinates of the circle you're looking for.

As @wingnut suggested, you can bump the `n_points` up or down to get more fine-grain detail in your circle.

PS: You can simplify the two lines of the `get_all_circle_coords` function into one single line, but I decided to keep them separate for the sake of clarity and readability.

**Edit**: I made a couple of small edits to make things a bit more reusable. Also, thanks @Mike T for the tip about `math.tau`.

Comment: and you could even replace `2 * math.pi` with just `math.tau` (see [PEP 628](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0628/))